# SI representation of number in equation

Tags: algebra-precalculus

My lecturer is trying to be smart and tricky. This number $10^{-10}\ m^2$ When using in an equation is simply $1\times10^{-10}$ right?

Answer (score 1):

A number with an unit is not just the number in front of the unit. For example, $1+1=2$ but $1~\mathrm{m}+1~\mathrm{cm}=1.01~\mathrm{m}\ne 2~\mathrm m$.

Think of the $\rm m$ as a variable with unspecified positive value (the value is actually specified in SI, but in a form that is not mathematical).

Comment: $m^2$ is metres squared so if I was using it in a equation I would enter $1\times10^{-10}$?

Comment: @stuart: Enter? Enter where?

Comment: $10^{-10}\ m^2$

Comment: @stuart: How do I enter into an expression?

Comment: For example if $a=10^{-10}\ m^2$ and $E=477.89\times10^6$ then $Ea=477.89\times10^6\times1\times10^{-10}=4.779\times10^{-2}$

Comment: @stuart: No, $Ea = 477.89\times 10^6 \times 1\times 10^{-10}~\mathrm m^2=4.779\times 10^{-2}~\mathrm m^2$. Do not omit the $\mathrm m^2$. They are an *essential* part of the value.

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand the question well, but when you have some numbers, in physics, you (usually) need the relative unit of measure. Unless they are adimensional of course.

In your case, $10^{-10}$ m means 0.0000000001 meters, and when you have to insert it into an equation, to calculate something, you can write both $10^{-10}$ and $0.0000000001$. As you wish.

But remember the unit of measure!!

You cannot sum meters and centimetres, for example.

Answer (score 0):

There are some base units like meter, ampere, candela etc. in SI. When you want to work with them when solving an equation or otherwise manipulating physical formula, you must be careful to not lose them. E.g. $1\,\mathrm m+1\,\mathrm{cm}\ne2\,\mathrm m$. But what you also have is a set of prefixes, which you can view as e.g. $\mathrm c=10^{-2}$. Then $\mathrm{cm}=10^{-2}\,\mathrm m$, and addition mentioned above will work as

$$1\,\mathrm{m}+1\,\mathrm{cm}=1\,\mathrm m+10^{-2}\,\mathrm m=1.01\,\mathrm m.$$

Similarly for multiplication of units, you have e.g.

$$1\,\mathrm{mm}^3=(1\,\mathrm{mm})^3=(10^{-3}\,\mathrm m)^3=10^{-9}\,\mathrm m^3.$$

So, it's not as simple as merely plugging the number into the equation. You should treat the unit as an unspecified-valued variable, and take advantage of scaling prefixes like centi, kilo etc. to simplify final expression to avoid things like $5\,\mathrm{m}/\mathrm{km}$ (this one is equal to dimensionless $5\times10^{-3}$).